# New dryer, old outlet

Tags: electrical, dryer, temporary

We just moved into a rental and will only be there 4 months. The dryer plug is three prong and our dryer is 4. Our landlord is kind of useless so we're not sure if he'll make an effort to do anything for us because it's such a short stay.
Is there an adapter or plug we can use temporarily instead doing electrical work?

Comment: A quick google search will give you various adapters (http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/janitorial-maintenance/floor-care/grinders-polishers/dryer-adapter-cord-30a-540-0050-00-1-pack?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQjwwpm3BRDuh5awn4qJpLwBEiQAATTAQctvxpe-fvNEE0zMls5TJy-v2YN4dUr2M6qSJL2n6dkaAlq18P8HAQ)  I have no affiliation w/ that website or product, just a link that I found googling.

Comment: @sous2817 there's a good reason adapters like that don't have UL stamps on them. Not to mention, it looks like the one you've linked to has a 4-prong plug on it, so it wouldn't work for the OP anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The manufacturer's installation instructions should contain a section on how to properly install a three prong cord on the dryer.  Buy a three prong cord, and follow the instructions to install it.  Keep the 4 prong cord, in case the next place has a 4 prong receptacle.

If you don't have the manufacturer's installation instructions for the dryer, you can usually download a copy from the manufacturer's website. You'll just need to know the model number to look it up.

> ***WARNING***
>   Using unlisted adapters found on the internet, or building ones yourself, is a good way to injure/kill someone.